# Finding matrices correlation

Tags: data-analysis

I have two matrices (A and B) which have same rows and cols. I want to compare them in order to find if there is any row in which the associated values in matrix A are much less than values of the same row in the matrix B. 
e.g.

A: [5.5 5.8 5.9; 2.3 2.5 2.7; 9.1 9.2 9.0]
B: [5.6 5.3 5.7; 7.8 7.9 7.5; 9.0 9.5 8.9]

and I am interested in row 2 for which values are much less than the other matrix.

Comment: ... define a limiar, sum the rows of each matrix, and compare.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for:

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/measuring-correlation-between-two-matrices

Comment: @duffymo Actually in my case the cells in one row are intercorrelated and all are representing the number of same object but in different sample.